# Can iOS app bypass/skip the device passcode window if it knows the passcode

Tags: iphone, ios, security, password

To perform some important actions on iOS it's required to enter the device passcode, for example adding a VPN profile or installing custom settings config (new feature in iOS 14).

I wonder, is it possible for an app to do such actions bypassing/skipping the device passcode prompt window if it already knows the device passcode somehow. In other words, can an app enter the device passcode in the background without the user noticing it. Generally speaking, is it possible for a potentially malicious app to do bigger harm if it knows the device's passcode?
Thanks!

BTW I asked a similar question for macOS [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415380/can-malware-skip-the-administrator-password-popup-if-it-already-knows-the-passwo) and it seems that for macOS it's true.

Comment: Perhaps you can share some insight as to _why_ you're asking these questions? - It might be possible to answer your question as lot better if we knew why you're asking. There's a big difference between asking "should I as a normal user be concerned about this" (no), or "I happen to have the secret plans for a cold-fusion plant sitting on my iPhone, is this protected in any scenario imaginable?" (no)

Comment: @jksoegaard thanks for your comment and answer. Yes, let me share some high-level insight into why I asked those questions. I asked the iOS question just out of curiosity to understand is there any difference in the OS implementation compared to macOS regarding that credentials prompt mechanism. From your answer, I can conclude that iOS doesn't allow to legitimately bypass that, but it possible to do that on macOS. I am, as a normal user, fully satisfied with the guarantees that iOS provides.

Comment: @jksoegaard On macOS, on the other hand, there are things that you as a user can do to improve security. E.g. it's recommended to not run as an admin and use a standard account instead. I wanted to understand how to protect my admin password. Since if malware installed in the standard user scope reveals them I am in a bigger problem. 
So I basically wanted to how to manage my admin account.

Comment: @jksoegaard specifically I asked two additional questions:
1. Is it secure to put my admin credentials in a password manager (1Password) that I use from the standard user scope? [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1632014/store-computer-admin-password-in-the-password-manager)
2. Is it secure to always enter my admin credentials in the standard user scope when I need to do an admin action or it's better to switch the users? [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1632001/can-keylogger-record-the-admin-password-on-macos)

I hope this will help to better understand my intentions. Thanks!

Comment: Your conclusion is not what intended. The situation on macOS and iOS is similar. Neither system “allows” it, but either system could have a weakness that evildoers could exploit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually quite similar as for macOS:

The intention of the system is (ofcourse) that apps are not allowed to bypass/skip these passcode prompt windows, and they're not able to "just" put in a code if they happen to know.

Similarly on recent macOS versions, apps cannot "just" interact with controls in windows they have not shown themselves. You can however give apps permissions to do so (for example an app that enables you to create macros of actions within other programs would be a good example of when you actually want to allow this behavior).

However - as your question on macOS centered around malware, the same is true for malware on iOS - if the app does not "follow the rules" and intentionally exploit weaknesses in the operating system's implementation, it is theoretically possible for apps to bypass/skip these prompts if it knows the passcode itself. It isn't really "theoretical" as in "can't really be done in practice", but more like "it will be a bother to do".